# stomp/sockjs 404 not found error in jboss 6.4

Tags: tomcat, jboss, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I m trying to deploy [spring-websocket-portfolio](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio) sample app wich use stomp/sockjs client with spring j2ee server .

the same war package succeed in Tomcat7 and failed in jboss 6.4 and Tomcat6 with 404 error code .

The error in chrome console is :

> sockjs.js:1622 GET http://localhost:8080/spring-websocket-portfolio/portfolio/info?t=1466117690528 404 (Not Found)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Your server needs to be Servlet 3.0+ and should support the websocket API.
You'll find the list of officially supported servers in [Spring's reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-server), namely `Tomcat 7.0.47+, Jetty 9.1+, GlassFish 4.1+, WebLogic 12.1.3+, and Undertow 1.0+ (and WildFly 8.0+)`.

For JBoss 6.4, there are a few configuration tricks to enable websocket support in the container ([see this example](https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/tree/6.4.x/websocket-hello)).